# What does the +3 mean in G7+3?

Tags: chords, notation, jazz

It occurs in the piano part of Sleepy Lagoon (Harry James Orchestra). The context is as follows:

```
C    |    |    |    |    | Am   | D9    |     |

G7+3 / G96 / | G7+3 / G96 / | G7 / Em F#m° | G7
```

I don't think it's a misprint, as it comes up again as G9+3 a few bars later. Since this is big-band jazz, it isn't plausible to me that it indicates to the player not to omit the 3rd as they would never consider doing that anyway.

Comment: G96 is unusual too. Possibly aka G69. Sheet music shows G+ on 3rd bar of the Gs. Originally written in 3/4, Harry James plays 4/4.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure the 96s are really 69s. That's the way Sibelius interpreted them anyway and it fits well enough.

Comment: Curious: Would G69 (or G96) be what I think of as a G7 add 9, 13?  I'm not familiar with that notation.

Comment: @BrianTung it's a major triad with an added 6th and 9th. There is no 7th.

Comment: Things are different in the guitar world, I see. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a really round about way of notating a G7sus4.  The `+` is telling you to raise the note and the `3` is referring to the third of the chord so it's telling you to raise the 3rd. Since a raised major 3rd is just a 4th you'll typically see this chord as just G7sus4 which tells you to play a G7 with a 4th instead of a 3rd.

If you even [search the chord symbol on jguitar](http://jguitar.com/chordsearch?chordsearch=G7%2B3&labels=none) it will display the results for G7+3, but name all the chords it shows G7sus4.

Comment: I did hear a sus 4 in there, but why on earth it should be thought of as an augmented 3rd, - there's no point! Your answer is right, though, but the reasoning (not yours!) defies logic. A sus 4 is never going to be a +3. G11 might be closer...(without a 9).

Comment: @Tim I agree completely. You'll never see me use it.

Comment: Maybe someone felt it shouldn't be called a suspension if it's not **really** a suspension?

Comment: @ToddWilcox true, but then you go down a notation/theory/terminology rabbit hole. While it's true that sometimes a sus chord does function like the suspension non harmonic tone most of the time the sus is more used as a substitute for the third which in that case you don't want to be thinking of the tone as a third at all. Even if you were looking at the chords as quatal or quintal stacks which we don't have good chord symbols to denote , it doesn't make sense to refer to the tone as a 3rd as the system doesn't utilize them and would be more confusing than helpful.

Comment: I should have realised. I knew + means raised, not added. But I was blinded by the novelty of it.